# Why is there no BottomNavigation for Android included in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative and confused that there is no Android `BottomNavigation` included

[image]

(image source: https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/)

What's the reason for this and what's the best practive way to get one? (with and without `expo`)

Comment: You could try react navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use one of the existing React Native navigation libraries

Try using it [reactNvigation](https://reactnavigation.org/en/)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html

or use [NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#footer-tabs-def-headref)

Comment: thanks but why is it not included in the core react-native?